# Unable to add window in Android

Tags: java, android

In my dev console, I get the following error:

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@405126b8 is not valid; is your activity running?`

It's the follow line: `alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();`

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();

        LoadData();
}
```

I dont no whats wrong.

Comment: is this the onCreate method of Main, or of an inner class of Main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a bad context here, try to use the right context. See this,

[Bad token Exception](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/07/08/badtokenexception-android-dialog-getapplicationcontext.html)

Comment: The article you've linked to suggests using `this` (the Activity) instead of the application context.  The asker appears to already be doing this.

Comment: @Aaron V I had not sent him the link to rectify his error, I had sent him to know that why he is getting such an error. So, he can rectify the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if an activity is already considered to be "running" in onCreate. Have you tried the same code in onResume()?

Better yet, overwrite onCreateDialog() and later showDialog(). (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Finally, you don't seem to set any properties on the Builder before creating it - no title, no message - maybe one of those is required?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error reported once in a while from some of my apps, and here's what solved it for me:

```
if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
{
    //show dialog
}
```

All the other answers out there seem to be doing weird things like iterating through the list of running activities, but this is much simpler and seems to do the trick.